# PHP - How to add a function that terminates form processing when a value is empty?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, email

I have a form on my website with a simple PHP code that sends the values from the form to my email. I keep receiving empty emails with no fields filled out, even though i have made it required in the HTML code, so i'm pretty sure it is caused by some kind of crawlers. I have a robots.txt file, so the only thing i can come up with is terminating the form processing whenever it tries to send something with an empty value. The question is, how do i add this to my existing code?

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$fullname = $_POST ['name'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$emne = $_POST ['subject'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];
$to = "kubilayc414@gmail.com";

mail ($to, $emne, $message, "From " . $fullname . " - " . $email);
echo "<h2>Your message is sent. Thank you for your email.</h2>"
?>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST ['name']) && !empty($_POST ['email']) && !empty($_POST ['subject']) && !empty($_POST ['message'])){
    $fullname = $_POST ['name'];
    $email = $_POST ['email'];
    $emne = $_POST ['subject'];
    $message = $_POST ['message'];
    $to = "kubilayc414@gmail.com"; 
    if(mail ($to, $emne, $message, "From " . $fullname . " - " . $email)){
        echo "<h2>Your message is sent. Thank you for your email.</h2>";
    } else {
        echo 'Something wrong please try again later';
    }
} elseif(empty($_POST ['name'])){
    echo 'Name filed was empty';
} elseif(empty($_POST ['email'])){
     echo 'Email filed was empty';
} elseif(empty($_POST ['subject'])){
     echo 'Subject filed was empty';
} elseif(empty($_POST ['message'])){
     echo 'Message filed was empty';
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the entire `POST` array for empty like:

```
foreach($_POST as $post)
{
    if( empty($post) )
    {
        exit;
        // return some error message from here
    }
}

// Code to send email here
```

Or put an If condition like:

```
if( !empty($to) && !empty($emne) && !empty($message) && !empty($fullname) && !empty($email) )
{
    // Email send code here
}
else
{
    // Return error message from here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do i just insert i below my current code? :)